# want to implement License check for the app which has APK expansion files

Tags: android, android-lvl, apk-expansion-files

I have an app which is more than 50MB, for that i have implemented APK Expansion files. I want to make this app as licensed. Is it required to implement license check again for this? or will it automatically check for licensing.Please clarify?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not required to implement the license check again. expansion files library along with license library will check for license.

Comment: but if we need to customize Policy with custom validity grace period and retry count then what is the solution?